# Separation of variables in the PDE $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm stuck trying to work with the constants to the solution to the SOV problem

Given the following equation:  $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$ and the following conditions:  $u(0,t)=0=u(\pi,t)$, $u(x,0)=0$, $u_t(x,0)=8\sin^2(x)$, $t>0$, and $0\leq x\leq \pi.$

I've gotten as far as the following:

$u(x,t)=X_n(x)T_n(t)=\sum C_n\sin(nx)\left[A_n\cos(nct)+B_n\sin(nct)\right]$

Applying the two conditions that deal with $t$ we get

$0=u(x,0)=\sum C_n \sin(nx)[A_n]$

$8\sin^2(x)=u_t(x,0)=\sum C_n \sin(nx)[ncB_n]$

Comment: Why are all the arguments spatial and nothing is temporal?

Comment: I believe I just fixed that.

Comment: You really have only two sets of unknown coefficients, not three. You can rewrite $A_n C_n$ as $A'_n$ and $B_n C_n$ as $B'_n$.

Comment: That's where I'm kind of stuck - I'm not sure how to find these coefficients.

Comment: The next step is basically a determination of the Fourier series coefficients. Multiply both sides by an integrand which is an orthogonal function to your $\sin or \cos$ and integrate over its period. You will have only one non-zero integral from only one term in the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you do obtain.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n(nc)\sin(nx) = 8\sin^2(x)
$$
Now your eigenfunctions are orthogonal so lets multiple by $\sin(mx)$. When $n\neq m$, the sum is zero when integrated since the inner product is zero. Therefore, we have that $n = m$. Now, integrate over the x domain.
$$
B_n(nc)\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(nx)dx = 8\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(x)\sin(nx)dx
$$

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an error in my book or not, but the answer provided is $\sum\limits_{odds}\frac{32[(-1)^n-1}{\pi c n^2(n^2-4)}$

Comment: @emka your book is correct for the coefficient $B_n$. Note that the LHS  reduces to $B_n(nc)\frac{\pi}{2}$.